# Is there any methodology according to Bible to drive out demons from possessed people?

Tags: life-of-jesus, demons

There are numerous instances in the Bible where Jesus drives out demons from people who were possessed by them. If we take a general view of these events during the ministry of Jesus, we find that there were a number of such miracles performed by Jesus apart from other miracles. Sometimes these demons were themselves testifying about who Jesus was.

Recently we saw even Pope Francis performing what was called as exorcism on one of the visitors to him. So we can say that it is something similar to what Jesus was doing during His ministry.

The question is why this practice of driving out of demon is not very common nowadays in Christianity? And Is there any methodology according to Bible to drive out demons from possessed people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Acts 16:18 (NIV)  She kept this up for
>   many days. Finally Paul became so annoyed that he turned around and
>   said to the spirit, “**In the name of Jesus Christ I command you to come
>   out** of her!” At that moment the spirit left her.

Apostle Paul cast out the evil spirit by using the name of Jesus Christ. Anyone who believes Jesus Christ is given the power to drive out demons by faith and prayer.

> Mark 16:16-18 (NIV) Whoever believes and is baptized will be saved,
>   but whoever does not believe will be condemned. And these signs will
>   accompany those who believe: **In my name they will drive out
>   demons**; they will speak in new tongues; they will pick up snakes
>   with their hands; and when they drink deadly poison, it will not hurt
>   them at all; they will place their hands on sick people, and they will
>   get well.”

Some evil spirits are so powerful that it require more prayer and faith.

> Mark 9:29 (NIV) He replied, “This kind can come out only by prayer.”

As we can see in these verses, it's quite simple. It only require faith and prayer followed by pronouncing the name of Jesus Christ. But the most problematic here is having faith, which can be achieved through prayer and experience only. I myself once participated in an exorcism performed by our pastor. All we did was pray, sing songs and command the evil spirit to come out in the name of Jesus Christ, and it worked :-)

The methodology is simple. Prayer, Fasting and Commanding in the name of Jesus Christ. But it is not easy. Method is simple, but not easy to carry it out. It needs a lot of faith, personal relationship with God and patience.

Comment: "and it worked".  Please speak to that; how do you know it worked?

Comment: I want to add that fasting is also sometimes required: Matthew 17:21 and this kind doth not go forth except in prayer and fasting.'

Comment: @Mawia What I understand is that he is not doubting that it worked but if you could describe it in more detail.

Comment: @jayyeshu `how do you know it worked?` Because the evil spirit never disturbed the victim again. At first, the evil spirit was not willing to come out and was very restless, the more we prayed the more noise it would make with strange behaviors. Sometimes scary also. It was not easy. But the pastor did not give up easily. After praying for many days, at last the evil spirit gave up and left.

Comment: I also remember that the pastor would ask "Who are you?", then the spirit would reply through the victim "I roamed here and there and I found this body. I don't want to leave this place" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think one possible reason is that demon possession, while it's certainly still possible, I think is much rarer than it was during the days of Jesus. From a redemptive historical perspective, the fact that there seemed to be a lot more demonic activity during the days of Christ should not surprise us; surely demons would be working hard at the pivotal moment of all of history!

Comment: You tried to answer as to why it is not common nowadays. You could have given some more details in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, one of the practices is to pray and ask help to the Archangel Michael, who is the one that has the power to fight and destroy the devil and all of it's forms.

See the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_%28archangel%29) article and have a look at all the artwork and pictures dedicated to him and you can understand why.

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't mention any connection to possession and the archangel Michael. Can you give more information as to who you heard that idea from?

Comment: Sorry, I linked the English version of the wiki article which is less extensive than the Italian one. I actually thought it was the same. In any case this http://www.ourcatholicprayers.com/the-saint-michael-prayer.html is another link which explains how can the Archangel  Michael assist us with the evil

Answer (score 0):

WE ARE TOLD IN SCRIPTURE TO RIST (he will flee) AND STAND FIRM AND PUT ARMOUR OF GOD(not cast out, command, rebuke, use Jesus name and lay hands ect). Nowhere in the word commands or instructs a believer to cast out demons and how to. What causes one to sin? Demons? I killed someone, demons made me do it?

The bible says The Scripture is clear on what the source of sin is:

Our Lusts -- "Let no one say when he is tempted, I am being tempted by God, for God cannot be tempted by evil, and He Himself does not tempt anyone. But each one is tempted when he is carried away and enticed by his own lust" (James 1:13,14). James says that our own lust is the reason for our sin, not demonic control.

The Flesh --"Now the deeds of the flesh are evident, which are: immorality, impurity, sensuality, idolatry, sorcery, enmities, strife, jealousy, outbursts of anger, disputes, dissensions, factions, envying, drunkenness, carousing, and things like these" (Gal. 5:19­21). Notice that these sins are not deeds of the devil. They are deeds of the "flesh." When we sin, our flesh is the problem. The responsibility lies with us. No outside force can be blamed.

Evil Hearts -- "For from within, out of the heart of men, proceed the evil thoughts, fornications, thefts, murders, adulteries, deeds of coveting and wickedness, as well as deceit, sensuality, envy, slander, pride and foolishness" (Mark 7:21,22). The evil thoughts and deeds of men come from their own wicked hearts. It is our own lusts, flesh, and evil hearts that cause us to sin, not the Devil and his demons.

Did Job cast out demons or rebuke them when he was attacked?

Would like to know if people cast out demons, where do they GO?
If many demons do they all go out as one?

I think that according to the word, the most powerful weapon a Christian has is the word of God preached for salvation. In Acts 2, when Peter preached Christ and him crucified, 3000 where added to the church.

People need to believe in Jesus and accept him as Lord. The people of the world will brought into the glorious light. With the Holy Spirit in us, no demon can occupy the same house. To cast out demons ect all one needs to do is use Gods word for salvation, and the power of the word will make them believe and become new creatures and no one even demons if resisted they FLEE.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE. When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent). This just doesn't read like an academic answer, and please - we actually don't want comments here! Also, if you could identify your faith tradition, that would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

**Is there any methodology according to Bible to drive out demons from possessed people?** Yes.

**The question is why this practice of driving out of demon is not very common nowadays in Christianity?** It actually occurs pretty often actually.

**And Is there any methodology according to Bible to drive out demons from possessed people?** With study you will find what I am about to say is true even if it sounds unbelievable. To do this we need some big truths in a row I suggest just reading over all the statements, even if you disagree, til the end.

Satan means adversary, usually taught as a fallen angel, which is a correct description from a perspective but leads to personification such as believing that Satan is One Angel and that is his name.

The fallen part means to fall out of peace.

One that Follows Satan also falls out of peace because of the same reason that Satan fell. to unpersonify it, the adversary fell out of peace came to you and you then fell out of peace. The result of both falling out of peace is an argument.

Spirit means attitude, so Devil means an evil spirit(attitude). We can see that the attitude of one that has fallen out of peace is considered an evil attitude. Diablos means devil, and a demon is a characteristic of the attitude.

Therefore the demon can be categorized into three categories: Angry, Depressed, or Anxious.

The Holy Spirit is the attitude of peace, and by three methods the demons can be cast out.

**The Angry Spirit**
God teaches us through Psychology that anger is caused by "the decision to fix the threatening behavior". So to cast this devil out we do not resist the evil person, if he takes we give more, if he hits we let him hit more. Once the display of nonthreatening behavior is realized, no longer will the decision to fix the threatening behavior need to be made.

**The Depressed Spirit**
Depression is caused when the error causes anger to the self. So then faith, words of encouragement, self forgiveness, and righting other wrongs even if the error can no longer fixed will cast out this demon. So we give generously to balance errors, or simply accept the forgiveness.

**The Anxious Spirit**
Worry and fear cause anxiety, so by nonthreatening behavior coming in weakness, love, with blessings, and service this devil can be cast out.

Yet in all of these, Faith in humility prevents the denial which leads to anger and depression as stated in the stages of grief. Yet with forgiveness offered by the death of the Jesus. Acceptance can be made and the attitude can enter into peace.